# Accidentally deleted /bin/su

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, su

I was working in `/bin` on my Ubuntu system and ended up deleting `su` via a typing error while trying to do other editing. So now I have no way of swapping back and forth between users and root.

I have tried grabbing a `su` file off my other computer and putting it in `/bin` in order to get a temp work around, but it still says permission denied, but since I'm logged in as root I tried to `chown` it to root (successfully), but I'm still not able to swap users and am getting the Permission Denied failure.

Is there any quick way of recovery, or am I going to have to do a recovery of some sort?

Comment: What OS are you running? If Linux, since you're already root, just reinstall the package that provides `su`. I can post an answer if you give us your OS but on Debian based systems, that would be `apt-get install --reinstall login`

Comment: Oh sorry, I am running Ubuntu 12.04...And thank you, just reinstalling login has everything back up and going.

Comment: Cool. I just posted an answer, please [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) so the question can be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 3):

The `su` binary is provided by the `login` package. You can reinstall it and get your `su` back by running

```
apt-get install --reinstall login
```

This assumes that you have root access of course but since you said you still have a root session open, that shouldn't be a problem.